# Swift: Creating a function and calling it multiple times?

Tags: swift

I am very new to Swift and I can't find an answer to my qustion. 
I am working on an app that will do a lot of the same functions but on separate button pushes. I could reduce my code and time updating greatly if I am able to write a function or action and just call it by name on a button push. 
Does Swift have a way to do something like this:

```
Func doMath {
var answer = 1+1
var answer2 = 2+2
}

Func buttonPush {
call doMath
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an IBAction. Using the Assistant view hold the control key and drag it into your code. Then change the connection type to Action and give it a useful name.

From inside your IBAction you can do any maths or call any maths function you need. Using functions to minimise code duplication is a good idea.

Here's an example of an Action that starts a timer.

```
@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I sugguest you do some examples that use IBAction. 
I liked the [Ray Wenderlich ones myself.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/swift-language-tutorials)

Here is some code for creating a function that takes two integer parameters. It's taken from the Apple developer documentation.
[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID159) hopefully that's what you need.

```
func halfOpenRangeLength(start: Int, end: Int) -> Int {
return end - start
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. How would I call this action from a button push?
    self.play?

Comment: When you Ctrl drag from the storyboard to code it will link the button to whatever action you create

Comment: Will that work for multiple actions on one button? i am working an a basic trivia game, so I would like to code actions like switching teams, adding points, and generating a new question. If team 1 gets it right I would like to do all three, if they get it wrong, I would like to only do 2.

Comment: If team1 gets it right call these individual actions: addPoints, switchTeams, generateQuestion. 
If team1is wrong: switchTeams, generateQuestion.

Comment: You could have different procedures based on context set within the code. I really recommend you check out some tutorials. The early ones often cover topics like IBActions and IBOutlets and you'll be able use the code from them in your quiz.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I was really hoping swift had something similar to .Net so I could create all my actions and call them with a couple words anytime I need and in any order.

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer that might help. What you need is very easily done in swift